# C# Quartz Schedule Method Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I have an `async` method and scheduled to run there every 10 minutes. However, it only run the first time.

**Application_Start**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    JobScheduler.Start().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

**JobScheduler**

```
public static class JobScheduler
{
    public static async Task Start()
    {
        try
        {
            NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
            };
            StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
            IScheduler scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

            await scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Service>()
                .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInMinutes(10)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();

            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
        catch (SchedulerException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se);
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public class Service : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\pacote\IDGLog.txt", true))
        {
            await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know what I need to do to run continuously

Comment: did you debug your Execute method by putting breakpoint? And make sure you already have that directory, if the directory not exits then it throws exception

Answer (score 0):

My *Spidey Senses* tells me `scheduler` is falling out of scope, your `Job` runs once because its `StartNow` then everything gets cleaned up

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the method `await scheduler.Start();` at the end. It should work.